# Rotationally symmetric hypersurfaces with mean curvature bounded away from 0

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know that the rotationally symmetric hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with constant mean curvature are the hyperplane, sphere, cylinder, catenoid, nodoid, and unduloid. Are there any significant restrictions on rotationally symmetric hypersurfaces with mean curvature bounded away from 0?